# Is there a node like MixShader but for the displacement slot?

Tags: node-editor, displacement

So I want to apply two different materials and their displacements to an object but I was only able to keyframe the shaders using the mixshader node. Is there a similar node which can be used to keyframe two displacements? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the factor of a *Color > MixRGB* to switch from an image to another, and plug the *MixRGB* into the *Displacement* node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!
I was trying a million other ways to solve this but wasn't successful.